# Calculating forces on a truss

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, physics

[image]

I need to find certain forces of the truss shown above, and I am asked to calculate the forces with a matrix.

The given values are

```
Lx = 3.8; Ly = 6; WB = 900; WC = 400l FE = 500; FF = -750;
```

I calculated the diagonal parts to be

```
mag = Sqrt[Lx^2 + Ly^2];
```

I am being asked

> Determine the force RDy; determine the force TEF; determine the force TFC.

I started by making a 12 X 12 matrix:

[image]

Comment: This is not, per se, a Mathematica problem, unless you are encountering difficulties with the code (which, incidentally, you should share as text and not images).

Comment: there were problems in posting the code for the matrix which is why I had to post as an image

Comment: What problems? See if these instructions can help you: [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/27951)